# ReferenceError: jsonp not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

So I am making an ajax request in jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.success);
        }
    });
```

This is what I want to receive from the url:

```
jsonp({
"success": true,
}
)
```

But I keep getting this error - ReferenceError: jsonp is not defined

what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

P.S: Testing on FF

Comment: Just don't set the `jsonpCallback` option. Does the server always return the response in that format, calling a `jsonp` function?

Comment: Got the answer! I have to set but not to callback. Instead I have to put jsonCallback: "jsonp" because is the default callback from the proxy im using.

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a whie I got the solution:
  instead of setting the jsonCallback : "callback" I changed it to

```
jsonCallback: "jsonp"
```

Because that is the default callback my proxy returns.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "jsoncallback is not defined " message in a cross domain ajax call.

After a lot of search I found like adding 
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback'
gave me response as an object.